# How can we say that the area of any circle or circular based shape is finite?

Tags: area, pi

I am saying this because the area of the circle is pi * radius * radius. We know that pi is a never ending value. So, if some one says I need a circle of 3 metre square area to make a rim of the wheel. How can I make so? The value of pi is non-terminating - not a practical value. Also, does it mean that area of a square is finite but area of circle is not finite. But, if area of circle is not finite, then how can I see/visualize it.

Comment: For the area to be not finite it would have to be larger than any natural number, which is evidently false as the area of your supposed wheel is much less than 400 billion square km

Comment: I think you may be confused. When we say something is finite, we mean that that thing is not infinity (or negative infinity). In the case of $\pi$, $1 \leq \pi \leq 4$.

Comment: I mean the  value of pi cannot be expressed as any number. You can do approximation by saying 22/7 or something, but it is not true. So, if you multiply any number with pi ( whose value is not still) what will you get?

Comment: a multiple of $\pi$ of course. It can be represented with that letter, we just cannot represent it decimally with finite non-zero digits.

Answer (score 2):

Non terminating doesn't mean infinite.  pi is a *finite* number of a value between 3 and 3 1/4.  The *decimal expansion* is infinite but the *value* is finite.  pi is between 3 and 4.  Go one more place value and we see pi is between 3.1 and 3.2.  Go another place value and we see pi is between 3.14 and 3.15, and so on forever.  The *precision* of pi is infinite but it's value is simply a finite number like any other.

To get an area of 3 square meters you do:

$ A = \pi*r^2 = 3 $

$r^2 = \frac{3}{\pi} $

$ r = \sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}}$

That number is a finite number. According to my calculator it is approximately 0.97720502380583984317276924567669...  Like $\pi$, this number is non-terminating so I can't express it exactly.  So I'll say r = 0.977 and that is within a millimeter of what we need.  If I want to measure it within the diameter of a helium atom I round it off to 10 place values.  So r = 0.977205024 meters minus about 1/5 of a helium atom.

Answer (score 0):

A shape that is completely inside of another shape has a smaller area. A circle of radius 1 centered at the origin may be placed inside of a square with corners at (-1,-1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (1,1). The area of such a square is 4, and so the area of the circle must be less than 4.

Answer (score -1):

All space (area) is infinite.  Measurements express our understanding of such via finite rounding.  That is to say, in measuring we express a point as finite - when in fact a point has an area made up of an infinite number of "points."

Comment: Wow. Everything in the post is wrong. To begin with a point, to quote Euclid "is that which has no part". A  point is a single point and is not made of infinite points. Each point is distinct and "made of" on point.  Second, area is not measured by the number of points. That finite areas have infinite points is irrelevant.  Area is the span of which points occupy and not the quantity of the points. Third, this isn't about the number of points in a circle but the nature of $\pi$ haven't infinite representation. Which is simply a confusion of "infinite" in expression with infinite in value.